# How to pass a Global variable into a class in C#

Tags: c#

I am struggling to find a solution to pass a global variable into a class.

I've tried to create a public function that get the global variable's value it seem like I can't call that function from the class.

Below is my code:

```
    string latitude = null;
    string longitude = null;
    public string geturl() {
        return  latitude + "," + longitude;
    }

    public Form1() {
        Watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

        Watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;
        InitializeComponent();
        Watcher.Start();
        ChromiumWebBrowser a = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        panel1.Controls.Add(a);
        a.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        a.Load("https://drive.google.com/open?id=12j590lCugajX1T64DHKcSiX9RwwBkAeF&usp=sharing");
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        BrowserLifeSpanHandler blsh = new BrowserLifeSpanHandler();
        a.LifeSpanHandler = blsh;      
    }

    public GeoCoordinateWatcher Watcher = null;

    private void Watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready){
            // Display the latitude and longitude.
            if (Watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown){
                latitude = "Cannot find location data";
            } else {
                latitude = Watcher.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString();
                longitude = Watcher.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public class BrowserLifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler {
        public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName,
            WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo,
            IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser) {               
            newBrowser = null;
            MessageBox.Show(targetUrl);
            ChromiumWebBrowser b = new ChromiumWebBrowser(targetUrl);
            return false;
        }

        public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser) {
            //
        }

        public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser) {
            return false;
        }

        public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser) {
            //nothing
        }
    }
```

How can I pass the values of the `string geturl()` function into the `BrowserLifeSpanHandler` class?

Comment: There are no global variables in C#. The code isn’t an [mcve] so I assume the variables and the geturl() are inside class Form1 (name classes better, by the way). It’s unclear if you just want to give the values to the instance of the other class (so fields or a method call) or do you want it to be able to ask for the values (so a reference to the first object so that it can ask about them). Could you clarify the question on how the data should be shared?

Comment: IT seems that you didn't share your full code.  If you are declaring class inside class then don't do it.

Comment: You can make a constructor taking in the string, or a public method that takes a string or define a public string property in that class and set it to the result of `geturl()`

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support the concept of a "global variable" as you may know it for instance from javascript.

If you really need something like this (you should reconsider your design first), you can define a [static class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

```
public static class MyGlobals {
    public static int p1 {get;set;}
    public static string p2 {get;set;}

    public static string getValue() {
        return "somevalue";
    }


}
```

Then you can access the property values and methods from anywhere in the code

```
int v = MyGlobals.p1;
string s = MyGlobals.getValue();
```